# Can someone explain me the use of getHeaderText() method in magento

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5

in `block/adminhtml/items.php` file there is one method

```
public function getHeaderText()
{
    $item = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_bhakti_magento2_items');
    if ($item->getId()) {
        return __("Edit Item '%1'", $this->escapeHtml($item->getName()));
    } else {
        return __('New Item');
    }
}
```

I dont get how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function **`getHeaderText()`** sets the page heading in the admin form. The usage is simple.

When Magento finds the **ID** parameter, it assumes that the page an edit form. Based on that it sets the page heading like:

> Edit Item [Item Name]

If the ID is not available, it sets the form heading as the new item form.

Below is the simple demonstration of the scenario:

**New Record:**
[image: New record]

**Edit Record:**
[image: Edit Record]

Comment: @bhakti, glad that I could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

`getHeaderText()` is used to add the form title in your admin form.

Navigate to the following path

> vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php

You will get the function with name `getHeaderHtml()` which contains the `getHeaderText()` function.

```
<?php 

...
...

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getHeaderHtml()
{
    return '<h3 class="' . $this->getHeaderCssClass() . '">' . $this->getHeaderText() . '</h3>';
}
```